# Incorrect member offset calculated by compiler in constructor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

VC++ compiler for unknown reason generates incorrect member offsets in constructor for a class with below structure:

```
class AlignTest
{
public:
    enum TEnum : char
    {
        one,
        two
    };
protected:
    int& ref;
    char c;
    size_t keyVar;
public:
    AlignTest(int& x. size_t other = 0) : ref(x)
    {
        c = 1;
        keyVar = other;
    }
    void Print();
};
```

Because of unknown reason during constructor execution keyVar assignment is writing at address this+0x09 but keyVar is actually at this+0x10 due to alignment. Surprisingly when running Print method, code is generated correctly and resolves keyVar to this+0x10.

Few observations:

- Adding alignof(8) to keyVar solves the problem
- moving constructor's definition to cpp file solves the problem
- same issue when using initialization list in header
- was unable to reproduce simplified version in different project on newer compiler (working on it)
- Checked headers if every type used in class is well known when constructor is defined.
- running debug, with optimization turned off, x64, toolset: windowsapplicationfordrivers10.0, VS2017.

It seems that constructor code does not take into account keyVar alignment. Is there some standard/compiler limitation or it's just compilers bug/side effect?

Update with piece of disassembled code by VS, note offset from "this" address.

Within constructor from .h file:

```
keyVar = other;
00007FF76C32D4DB 48 8B 44 24 08       mov         rax,qword ptr [this]  
00007FF76C32D4E0 48 8B 4C 24 18       mov         rcx,qword ptr [other]  
00007FF76C32D4E5 48 89 48 09          mov         qword ptr [rax+9],rcx
```

Within Print method:

```
size_t tmp2 = keyVar;
00007FF76C3918D0 48 8B 84 24 40 02 00 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [this]  
00007FF76C3918D8 48 8B 40 10          mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+10h]  
00007FF76C3918DC 48 89 44 24 68       mov         qword ptr [rsp+68h],rax
```

**Update**

Seems like something's wrong with original project. I've moved suspicious classes to separate project, used same compile tools and couldn't reproduce.

On Monday will start other way around - removing things from original project and see what will make a difference.

Comment: If you are *certain* it is a bug, then I would recommend reporting it to the MSVC team.. so they can fix it.

Comment: It's unclear; how are you certain this is the case? None of the you posted code indicates that it is at address 0x09 in the constructor.

Comment: I'm not certain at all. I don't know even c++ spec that well to tell if I'm not falling into ill-formatted or undefined behavior category. And there are also tons of compiler specific details and behaviors.

Comment: While checking addresses I'm looking at VS debugger's disassembler. I do not decode bytecode myself and rely on what VS shows. Will update post with it.

Comment: Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/94vwqD) simillar to what you see, or can you expand the godbolt example to show it?

Comment: If you put up a [mcve] it's easier to verify/test for others. Are you using the latest VS version (16.3.9)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, your code optimized out reference as I can understand it and alignment in constructor seems correct. Also no, im not using latest compiler and Im working on minimal example which I can show here.

Comment: @DawidW Please include the version of VS you use too. If there's an issue with an old version, chances are that someone here knows about it or manages to link it with some other known issue.

Comment: @DawidW Your update supports what is repeatedly mentioned here. Creating a minimal reproducible example often reveals a) the problem you are trying to solve or b) a totally different problem that you couldn't have possibly included in the question to start with.

Comment: Your project most likely has some unwanted compiler flags.

Comment: If I had to guess: the header file is included in two source files built with different pack levels, either via `#pragma pack` directive or `/Zp` compiler option. As a result, the program effectively contains ODR violation - different pieces don't agree on the binary layout of the class.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have same thing on my mind. It may be that some header where constructor is included has leaked pack pragma. Will investigate it on Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Igor Tandetnik suggested problem was in different pack level in compilation unit with constructor (1) and in unit with print method (8). Found not reverted pack(1) directive in one of project's header.